# How can I use an instance variable of an object created inside the object's class. I keep getting "cannot find symbol"

Tags: java

```
class _temp
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        _temp object = new _temp();

        int x = 1;
        System.out.println("x = " + object.x);
    } 
}
```

When I try to compile this code the following error is shown :

```
    _temp.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
            System.out.println("x = " + object.x);
                                              ^
 symbol:   variable x
 location: variable object of type _temp
 1 error
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thank You.

Comment: Where is "x" in you class "_temp" ?

Comment: I would suggest you to go through some Java tutorials (basic object oriented) as it seems like you might not have the proper knowlege yet.